# Left margin is different in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Using CSS3 I am trying to display search box with glass image. I am doing it basically by placing a image on text box and setting its `left-margin`. My code is here:

```
<body>
    <form id="header-search">
        <input type="text" class="searchbox" /><input type="submit" class="button" value="" />
    </form>
</body>



#header-search{overflow:auto;}

#header-search input.searchbox 
{
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px; 
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;


    border-top-left-radius:5px;  
    -webkit-top-left-radius:5px; 
    -moz-left-radius:5px;

     border:1px solid #8e8e8e;

     background-color:white;
     height:16px;
     padding:4px;
     padding-left:28px;
     padding-right:10px;
     color:#4a4a4a;
     float:left;

 }

#header-search input.button{
    border:0px dashed red;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 0 -185px;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background:transparent url(../images/SearchImage.png) center center  no-repeat;
    float:left;
}
```

**UPDATE**

1. I am not using em rather px
2. I have tried different css reset.
3. please see image for details difference.
4. I have done this code in new css/ html file where there is no other line of code.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Using `position:absolute` seems to be a more reliable approach for this kind of thing.

HTML

```
<form id="header-search">
    <div class='relative'>
    <input type="text" class="searchbox" /><input type="submit" class="button" value="" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.relative {
  position:relative;
}
.relative .button {
  position:absolute; 
  left: 20px;
  z-index:1;
}
```

---

You may want to make this css more specific to this search input rather than all `.button`'s etc

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are not specifying a width of your search input box.
If you do that, you method will work.

Else, of course, the better way is to use position:absolute to position your button.
This will ensure the layout across all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to place image for search input box , you can try this http://jsfiddle.net/HmKZQ/1/
2. If you need the button for click then you can try this
   http://jsfiddle.net/HmKZQ/3/

Comment: I think the reason it is written with a button is so that people can click it to start the search.

Comment: @Sowmya thanks, it fixed the problem.

Can you please explain background:transparent url(http://www.hayemaker.com/bookazine/Portals/_default/Skins/Bookazine/img/search-icon.gif) 0 10%  no-repeat; I couldn't find some of the options. Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain what is meaning by 0 10%  in CSS ?

Comment: @haansi 0 is the x position and 10% is the y position of the background image. In case if you need padding for bg image you can use this options otherwise other options like left/center/right works fine

Comment: That 0 10% I have used for the first example to give bg image for input box. In your case you need not to use tat. I have edited the fiddle check this http://jsfiddle.net/HmKZQ/4/